# How to parse data between tags from a text file in C

Tags: c, parsing, text, tags

I want to print the data between tags from a text file using C.

Input statement : 
(PERSON) Mark Zuckerberg (/PERSON) is a entrepreneur from (LOCATION) USA (/LOCATION). He is also the CEO of (ORGANIZATION) Facebook (/ORGANIZATION).

Output: Mark Zuckerberg USA Facebook.

My Program code is :

```
    const char* getfield(char* line, int num)
    {
        const char* tok;
        for (tok = strtok(line, "/>");
                tok && *tok;
                tok = strtok(NULL, "<\n"))
        {
            if (!--num)
                return tok;
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    int main()
    {
        char line[500000];
        while (fgets(line, 500000, stdin))
        {
            char* tmp = strdup(line);
            printf(" %s\n", getfield(tmp, 2));
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
```

It is only printing Mark Zuckerberg. Other data between tags are not showing ? Can someone please help where I went wrong ? I have just started learning file processing in C, so guidance is highly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Please replace "(" by "<" and ")" by "/>".

Comment: Try to debug it first... using your favorite debugger.

Comment: I think your input statement contains no tags (just a single ">"). Please edit the question to fix the input statement.

Comment: 0X0nosugar - Please check the edited part.

Comment: @Michael Walz Please check the edited part.

Comment: BTW, you could've put your opening/close tags in a code block: `<person>Mark Z</person>`

Comment: If you want to do this in C, why did you add tag for `c++`?  They are different languages, for example, C++ has `std::string` class and C doesn't.  I suggest you remove the C++ tag in your post.

Answer (score 2):

Your `getfield` don't do what you want I guess. On example string (remplacing parenthesis) your `for` loop starts `strtok` will cut at the first ">" (`strtok` uses any of the characters as delimiter) so the one after the 1st "PERSON". After that you only cut for ">\n" so at end of this tag. With a big enough `num` it would give (inside the loop):

```
<PERSON
 Mark Zuckerberg 
/PERSON> is a entrepreneur from 
LOCATION> USA 
/LOCATION>. He is also the CEO of 
ORGANIZATION> Facebook 
/ORGANIZATION>
```

You should alternate searches: search for closing tag (>), then search for opening tag (<): in beetween is the content of 1st tag. Then skip the closing tag and start again the same until the end. Something like:

```
char *gf(char *line, int num) {
  char *n1, *n2;
  // comments are for the 1st loop
  // search end of 1st tag (opening)
  n1 = strtok(line, ">\n");
  while(n1) {
    // search begin of 2nd tag (correp. closing)
    n2 = strtok(NULL, "<");
    // this one is good, shall we return it?
    if (num == 0) {
      return(n2);
    }
    printf("Found: %s\n", n2);
    // search end 2nd tag (have to skip it)
    n1 = strtok(NULL, ">\n");
    // search end of 3rd tag (opening), then loop (same situation)
    n1 = strtok(NULL, ">\n");
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Note that this code is not very nice. If you have ">" or "<" inside regular text it will go wrong (as do you own code, BTW). And it don't stop properly if string don't ends with a \n.

Note bis: whatever if you need a robust approach you will have to *read* tags. I mean find a tag (stuff beetween "<" and ">"), then find the corresponding closing tag (same, but with the / and the same content), and then only get the text inside or generate an error.

EDIT: I changed the function so that it returns the `num`th element. You will now have to deal with a `main()` function able to call this function several times, with increasing values of `num`, storing (or printing) the result until getting NULL answer.
As home work you will have to find how to manage the main string (line) in `main` so that successive calls are possible (else you will really only get the first tag) :)

Comment: Applied your approach, still in same position. It is reading the data between the first tags only i.e, It is only printing Mark Zuckerberg. Can same one edit the code please ?

Comment: I think you don't understand my code. With the same input than you it will prints "Mark Zuckerberg" + "USA" + "Facebook" (really coded an ran on my machine). It is only a print, of course. If you want all the elements you have return them. In your code you seems to always ask for the "2"nd element...

Answer (score 1):

Your `fgets()` call is reading the entire line.  Then you call `getfield()` and print the result.  You then discard the rest of what you read, try to read more, there isn't any more, and you exit your loop.  You need to keep looping as long as you have unprocessed data in `line`.

Edit:  Here's some sample code to get you started:

```
int main()
{
    char line[500000];
    while (fgets(line, 500000, stdin))
    {
        char *arg = line;
        const char *tok;
        while ((tok = getfield(arg, 2)) != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", tok);
            arg = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

But note that this isn't a real solution.  For one, it will give you the text outside of the tags as well as text inside the tags, so you will need to skip that.  For another, it won't really work properly if your input file contains more than one line.

Comment: How to do that ? Can you please show in code ? I am not able to figure this out.

Comment: You need to keep calling `strtok`, with `NULL` as the first argument, until you have consumed the entire line.  Only then should you read a new line and reset `strtok` by passing a non-`NULL` first argument.

Comment: Tried. Getting errors. Please show in code. I am new to this and not able to figure out anything.

Comment: See my edit above.  This is just a sample, not a real solution.  You will need spend some time working out the details for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:Changed `(` and `)` this to `<` and `>` respectiveley in the code and in the explanation. Thanks Tom.**

Here is the Solution. Try to Understand the code. Also, feel free to modify it to your needs. Basically, what you need to do is scan for the tags `<>` or/and `</>` by scanning for characters `<` and `>`. When you encounter the character `<` increment your index till you encounter the character `>`.Once you encounter `>` character then start copying the character following the `>` character till you encounter another `<` character and then repeat the process till you reach the null terminating Character `'\0'`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
//#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

void removeTags(char inpData[], int dataLen);

int main()
{
   char letter, fileData[400];
   int numLetters;
   FILE *pfile;
   pfile = fopen("test.txt", "r");

   if (pfile == NULL)
   {
     printf("Error!Can not open file");
   }
   else 
   {
    numLetters = 0;
    while ((letter = fgetc(pfile)) != EOF) 
    {
        fileData[numLetters] = letter;
        numLetters++;
    }
    fileData[numLetters] = '\0';
    printf("File Data:\n\n");
    printf("%s", fileData);
    printf("\nRemoving Tags.....\n");
    removeTags(fileData,numLetters);
}

return 0;
}

void removeTags(char inpData[],int inpLen)
{
   char character,temp[400];
   int index = 0,tindex=0;

   while (inpData[index] != '\0')
   {
      if ((inpData[index] >= 'A' && inpData[index] <= 'Z') || (inpData[index] >= 'a' && inpData[index] <= 'z') || inpData[index] == ' ' || inpData[index] == '.')
      {
        temp[tindex] = inpData[index];
        index++;
        tindex++;
      }
      else if (inpData[index] == '<')
      {
        while (inpData[index] != '>')
        {
            index++;
        }
        index++;
        temp[tindex] = ' ';
        if (tindex > 0)
        {
            tindex++;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
temp[tindex] = '\0';
printf("%s", temp);
}
```

Comment: The tags are supposed to be standard XML tags, delimited by angle brackets, not parentheses.  The edit at the bottom of the post explained that.

Comment: Oops!Sorry didn't see that will edit the code. Anyways thanks Tom Karzes for pointing it out.

Comment: Nice to answer the question quite literally, but I really don't see why the top test is necessary. Apart from being unnecessary, it also breaks for **all** other characters than the supplied list. The `<..>` could simply be moved up as the only necessary test. It may benefit from an end-of-line check in case of a missing `>`.