# Removing Tags from a file parsed in C

Tags: c, parsing, text

I want to print the data between tags from a text file using C.

Input statement :

```
<PERSON> Mark Zuckerberg </PERSON> is a entrepreneur from <LOCATION> USA </LOCATION>. He is also the CEO of <ORGANIZATION> Facebook </ORGANIZATION>.
```

Output: Mark Zuckerberg USA Facebook.

My Program code is :

```
const char* getfield(char* line, int num)
{
    const char* tok;
    for (tok = strtok(line, "/>");
        tok && *tok;
        tok = strtok(NULL, ">"))
    {
        if (!--num)
            return tok;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    char line[500000];
    while (fgets(line, 500000, stdin))
    {
        char *arg = line;
        const char *tok;
        while ((tok = getfield(arg, 2)) != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", tok);
            arg = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

My output is :

```
Mark Zuckerberg </PERSON

USA </LOCATION

Facebook </ORGANIZATION
```

I want to get rid of `</Tag` and get only Mark Zuckerberg USA Facebook as output. Where do I need to change the code?

Comment: That's an exact clone of [How to parse data between tags from a text file in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33523405/how-to-parse-data-between-tags-from-a-text-file-in-c). (Okay, the code has changed, but the question and probably the poster are the same.)

Comment: Yes. I am still having problem in this.

Comment: You've gotten detailed and helpful answers on this one, explaining the shortcomings and misconceptions of your code. Study them. SO isn't about asking the same question repeatedly until you get an answer you like.

Comment: is that mandatory to have id written in C? manipulating strings is C is always really painful; if it is not required, I would suggest using sed.

Comment: I am new to programming. So help is appreciated. I have changed the code as per suggestion and modified them. I am thankful to the helpers for guiding me. I just wanted to know where I am getting wrong and what will be the correct code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *getfield(char **sp){
    char *left; //point to <
    char *right;//point to >

    if((left = strchr(*sp, '<')) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if((right = strchr(left, '>')) == NULL)
        return NULL;

    size_t len = right - left;//if len == 1, tag is nothing(<>)
    char *tag = malloc(len);
    memcpy(tag, left + 1, len -1);
    tag[len-1] = '\0';

    char *etag = malloc(len + 3);
    sprintf(etag, "</%s>", tag);
    left = right + 1;
    if((right = strstr(left, etag)) == NULL)//right point to end tag
    {
        free(tag);
        free(etag);
        return NULL;
    }
    len = right - left;
    char *text = malloc(len + 1);
    memcpy(text, left, len);
    text[len] = '\0';

    *sp = right + strlen(etag);
    free(tag);
    free(etag);
    return text;
}

int main(void){
    char line[500000];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)){
        char *arg = line;
        char *text;

        while ((text = getfield(&arg)) != NULL){
            printf("%s\n", text);
            free(text);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is based on various assumptions

Comment: Thank You BLUEPIXY. Highly Appreciated.