# How to find text between two specific strings in c

Tags: c, string, c-strings, text-extraction

I want to extract only strings between `<AAA> and </AAA>`
how can i extract those?
please help
**Example :**
`<AAA>hello world</AAA>`
`this is a text`
`<AAA>this is another text</AAA>`
**Result :**
hello world 
this is another text

Comment: well you probably have to write your own text parser, but it really depends on tags. For example C has parser for html5, and i am sure xml parser can be found, but if your text is not a valid xml ot html, you'll have to write your own parser most likely/

Comment: sorry,let me say clearly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33538909/971127

Comment: There is a file that contains a series of text, some texts are between <p> and </p> (like : <p>text</p>) other texts are not. now i wan to extract those texts between <p>&</p> and save them into another file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your parsing needs are big enough you may look for parsing library, like [libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/). Otherwise [strstr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) is your friend:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *res;
    size_t len;
    const char *p1, *p2;
    char text[] = "<AAA>hello world</AAA>";

    p1 = strstr(text, "<AAA>");
    if (p1 == NULL) return -1;
    p1 += 5;
    p2 = strstr(p1, "</AAA>");
    if (p2 == NULL) return -2;
    len = p2 - p1;
    res = malloc(len + 1);
    if (res == NULL) return -3;
    strncpy(res, p1, len);
    res[len] = '\0';
    printf("'%s'\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

stdout:
'hello world'

or even better (no need to malloc):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const char *p1, *p2;
    char text[] = "<AAA>hello world</AAA>";

    p1 = strstr(text, "<AAA>");
    if (p1 == NULL) return -1;
    p1 += 5;
    p2 = strstr(p1, "</AAA>");
    if (p2 == NULL) return -2;
    printf("'%.*s'\n", (int)(p2 - p1), p1);
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/cbuDgn

Comment: thanks for your help. much appreciate:-)

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

- Read the whole file into a `char` array, reallocating this array if needed, null terminate the array.
- Use `strstr()` to find an occurrence of `"<AAA>"`. save position if found, done if not.
- From that position, use `strstr` to find `"</AAA>"`.
- output the text in between and restart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML libraries to parse your text, I recommand using [libexpat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) or [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) or [minixml](http://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z3), it is more easier to parse XML document with these libraries

For example for minixml (from official documentation of minixml):

**Loading XML**

You load an XML file using the mxmlLoadFile function:

```
FILE *fp;
mxml_node_t *tree;

fp = fopen("filename.xml", "r");
tree = mxmlLoadFile(NULL, fp,
                    MXML_TEXT_CALLBACK);
fclose(fp);
```

**mxmlEntityGetValue**

Get the character corresponding to a named entity.

```
int mxmlEntityGetValue ( 
    const char *name 
);
```

**Parameters**

```
name
    Entity name
```

**Return Value**

```
    Character value or -1 on error
```

Discussion

```
The entity name can also be a numeric constant. -1 is returned if the name is not known.
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and recommendation:-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    const char *srcStr = "<AAA>hello world</AAA> this is a text <AAA>this is another text</AAA>";
    const char *firstDelim = "<AAA>";
    const char *lastDelim = "</AAA>";
    char extStr[128] = "";
    int srcStrLen, firstDelimLen, lastDelimLen;
    int i, catIdx = 0;

    srcStrLen = strlen(srcStr);
    firstDelimLen = strlen(firstDelim);
    lastDelimLen = strlen(lastDelim);

    for (i=0; i<srcStrLen; i++){
        if (strncmp(&srcStr[i], firstDelim, firstDelimLen) == 0) {
            i += firstDelimLen;
            catIdx = i;
        }
        else if (strncmp(&srcStr[i], lastDelim, lastDelimLen) == 0) {
            strncat(extStr, &srcStr[catIdx], i - catIdx);
            i += lastDelimLen;
            if (i != srcStrLen){
                strcat(extStr, " ");
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", extStr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help and support :-)!!

Answer (score 0):

As it was said above it looks like XML-parser is you friend, see suggested libraries for XML-parsing. If by some miracle XML-parser can't parse your text, because it is not a valid XML, you can try and use HTML-parser(for example [gumbo-query](https://github.com/lazytiger/gumbo-query), or any other you can find). If HTML-parser does not work, well you will most likely have to write your own text-parser. This may be downwoted, because it does not really answer the question, but i think all other answers lack at least a suggestion of what to try if XML-parsers and XML-like parsers do not work.

Comment: wow! thank you very much. yes that's what i want,  much appreciated It seemed more logical way